# Bootstrap compatible responsive multi-level menu

Tags: web-development, menu, bootstrap

I'm trying to find a menu system that is compatible with [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) 3 and will do 3-4 levels of navigation.

I was looking at [Mega Dropdown](http://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html).
It *would* work pretty much exactly as we need it BUT there can only be one top level item - I need 3-4, not just a 'drop down' link. It also has some real issues with Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: I think this question would be better answered at Stack Overflow